# Print the number on the keypad or closest with movement restrictions

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I am working on this leetcode style python problem where we are given an integer "n" input where n is 1<n<200. I am only allowed to move down and to the right on the keypad and you have to start the "press" on the first number of the given input. For example, if given "180" we print out "180", because you start at "1" on the keypad and can make moves down and right to get to "8" and "0". But if we were given "98" we would have to print out "99" cause it is the closest number we can get to the original number with our movement restrictions.

This is the main logic i have been following,

Loop through the number given and see what valid moves you can make next are. I got stuck here cause I could not figure out how to see what valid moves are next and how to check the next number in the given number. I then tried to loop through and see if the current index of the number is in a certain list, like "if curr in [3, 6, 9]:"

then I would know that the only possible move is to either move down or "press" 9.
What I currently have is my 4th time rewriting my loops, so if you want to see my other attempts lmk! Here is what I currently have,

```
def closest(nums):
    keypad = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9],
        ['*', 0, '#']
    ]

    lst = []
    j = 0

    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        j = 0
        number = ''
        for j in range(0, len(nums[i])):
            curr = nums[i][j]

            while not check:
                print('here')
                for k in range(len(keypad)):
                    for l in range(len(keypad[k])):
                    # print(l, len(keypad[k]))
                        if keypad[k][l] != '*' and keypad[k][l] != '#':
                        # print(curr)
                            print(number)
                            if curr == '8':
                                 number = curr + '0'
                                 print('checking for 8', number)
                            elif curr in ['3','6','9']:
                                other = curr
                                number = number + curr + other
                                print('checking for right side', number)
                                lst.append(number)
                            # elif curr in [2,5]:
                                # didnt put the other cases here cause it just was not working.
                            else:
                                number += curr
                                print("check for left side", number)
                check = True

    return
```

Any help on how to think about how to solve questions like this would be great as well!

Comment: You intend to sometimes output "*" or "#" as well? What is the expected result for 90, or for 60?

Comment: For each number, I'd make a list of numbers that can follow it, e.g. `followers = [[0], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], [2,3,5,6,8,9,0], ` and so on.